# Azure Site Extension from private feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I want to install Azure Site Extension from Azure DevOps feed, and not nuget.org

I cannot find any instruction, except this link (5 years ago):
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/writing-a-site-extension-for-azure-websites/

Didn't work for me. Just stack on this screen:

[image]

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

**Update 1**

I browsed to kudu, and saw this:
[image]

Which gave me an idea to remove all previously installed site extensions. After doing this, I was able to see packages uploaded to myGet. So, now the main question. How to do this for Azure DevOps feed?

**Update 2**

I tried to set `SCM_SITEEXTENSIONS_FEED_URL` to my private feed in azure devops, but I get following error on kudu:

> Failed to retrieve site extensions from Gallery - An error has occurred. - Kudu.Contracts.SiteExtensions.InvalidEndpointException - Invalid remote feed url: https://****.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/****/nuget/v3/index.json

It looks like kudu cannot connect to feed. I tried to edit nuget.config on target website, and add `packageSourceCredentials`. didn't help. However, manual install with nuget cli from kudu powershell was successful.

Answer (score 0):

> So, now the main question. How to do this for Azure DevOps feed?

If you're trying to publish your site extension to Devops feed and get the feed URL, you can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-nuget?view=azure-devops) to do that. `Create a Devops feed in Azure Devops Artifacts and then=>Connect to Feed=>Nuget.exe`, you can find the url of your Devops feed here:

[image]

The format is always `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_packaging/FeedName/nuget/v3/index.json`. Maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I already tried that, but no luck. Please, take a look on updated question. I assume, if my project was public, so the feed, it could work.

Comment: Tried on public project feed. Didn't work too. No errors, no packages.

Comment: I checked the related documents again, but can't find anything about doing it by devops feed(needs PAT or other things for authentication) or even nuget.org. So I think you can try it with nuget.org, if the public nuget.org is not supported, then I think MyGet is the only website for this approach...

Comment: Thank you. I ended with creating an MyGet feed.